# how do I tell the string to read the 0 and not abort?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a string with numbers, including 0.
Unfortunately the string recognize the number 0 as \0 and finishes reading in.
Is there a way to interpret the 0 as 0 and read it?
My program is written in C++.

```
char buf[] = { 23, 4, 0, 234, 8}
string test(buf);
```

For this case the string 'test' will contain 23 and 4.
But for my case it should contain 23, 4, 0, 234 and 8.

These ways are not an option for me:

```
string test "abc\0\0def"s;            
string test R"abc\0\0def";
```

---

I tried to do `string test(buf, 5);` like the answer below suggested, but it didn't work:

```
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     char buf[]={10, 20, 0, 30, 40};
     string test(buf, 5);
     cout<<test.length()<<endl;
     char final[5]={0,0,0,0,0};

     strncpy(final, test.c_str(),5);
     
     for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
     {cout<<(int)final[u]<<endl;}
}
```

Comment: `arrayOfChars` is not a string with numbers, it's an array of characters. 0 and '\0' are the same. "A string with numbers" would be `char const* arrayOfChars[] = {"23", "4", "0", "234", "8"}`.

Comment: Hi. Yeah, you're right. This is just a very simplified excerpt from my code. The important thing is that there are numbers in it, so there are also some zeros. And they should also be read as 0's. Afterwards they are converted back into an integer array

Comment: `\0` denotes the end of a string. While it is possible to have a `std::string` with `\0` in it, most string related function will stop at `\0`, so why do you want to use `std::string` in that case?

Comment: @t.niese i have a string related Queue in my program. And i get the buf Array from another program playing together.

Comment: You are simply using the wrong container! std::string is made for strings and not for 8 bit integers. If you like to have a container with 8 bit integers, use std::vector. If I see  strncpy in connection with std::string and hard coded "size numbers", I would give you the hint to start with a good c++ beginner book!

Comment: so the problem is strcpy? @Klaus

Comment: @groenvit yes it is [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy)  
`[…]If, after copying the terminating null character from src, count is not reached, additional null characters are written to dest until the total of count characters have been written.[…]`, as I said in my first comment, most string related functions treat `\0` as the end of the string. If you want to work with data that is interrupted by `\0` then you should not use string related functions/classes or (if available)  set a flag that it should be handled as binary (e.g. when reading/writings streams).

Comment: @groenvit: No, the problem is that you mix C code and C++ and you did not use correct containers. A string is per definition a sequence of characters terminated by '\0' If you abuse containers for string to something totally different and mix it up with old style C-code, all of that stuff is a nightmare. Unmaintainable, error prone, hard to read and typically slower as real c++ code.

Comment: @Klaus a c-string is a sequence of chars terminated by `\0`, a `std::string` is a sequence of chars and its length is given by `length()` or its iterators and can contain `\0`. But having a `std::string` that contains `\0` prevents a correct usage in combination with functions like `strncpy` that expect a c-string.

Comment: @t.niese now it works. Thanks a lot. I was focusing on the wrong detail.

Comment: @Klaus yes you are right. i have not programmed with c++ but with c for quite long time and recently switched back. However, thanks for your help. Will hopefully do better next time;)

Comment: @t.niese: std::string provides a lot of functionality which is related to a string which means some kind of text. And using it with '\0' inside is simply not the idea behind the std::string type. If it has size or something else is not interesting at all. If you want to store numbers, use another container!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the amount of characters:

```
string test(buf, size(buf));
```

The use of [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) here requires `#include <iterator>`.

---

Instead of `size(buf)` you can simply write `5`, or obtain the array size in some different way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In this way, it interprets all numbers after the 0 as a 0 as well, thus aborting the process and filling the string with 0s.

Comment: It can also be done with strings / vectors if you give begin / end iterators. But more importantly, `unsigned char` should be used here since it looks like you are working with raw bytes.

Comment: @groenvit Can't reproduce, [works on my end](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TP8YK5). Can you show us the code you ended up with, that prints more zeroes that it should? See [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry @HolyBlackCat this is my first post. I edit the Question with a shortcut Code.

Comment: @groenvit Your constructed the string correctly. But when you copy the contents back to an array, `strncpy` stops at the first `0`. Use `memcpy` instead.

Comment: I was focusing on the wrong detail. Thanks a lot @HolyBlackCat now it works. Sorry for the bad question. Have a great day.

Comment: @groenvit You're welcome, and I don't think it's a bad question. Consider pressing the green tick to the left of the answer to [mark your question as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: is there a way to write a short summary for people with similar problems or is this superfluous anyway @HolyBlackCat ?

Comment: @groenvit Sure, you can write your own answer! There should be a button for that at the bottom of the page. (You can then put the green tick on it instead of this answer, if you want to.)

Answer (score 0):

Please use container types which are made for the functionality you want to use. For numbers, which are not characters at all, you should use `std::vector` instead, if you have the need of changing the size during runtime. If your data is constant, you can use `std::array` instead, which has less overhead.

Still there is the question, why you want to use `char` as data type, as you have numbers. Why not `uint8_t` or `int8_t`?

You should avoid using `strncpy` `strcpy` or even `memcpy` as long you are fine with all the available container types. Most all containers offer direct copy/move to target without calling any c-style functions.

BTW: `final` is a C++ keyword! Please do not use it for names of functions or variables or types please.

```
int main()
{
     std::vector<uint8_t> test{10, 20, 0, 30, 40};
     std::cout << test.size() << std::endl;
     std::vector<uint8_t> final_ = test; //copy, no special external func required

     // or if you really like to init 0 and overwrite
     std::vector<uint8_t> final2(5); // init with 5 times 0
     final2 = test; // copy;

     // cast is still needed to force cout to print number instead of char
     for ( auto c: final_ ) { std::cout << (uint16_t)c << std::endl; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. the problem here is that this is a time critical program. Therefore I want to save as much time as possible. The array comes from a different program as char Array. I admit that this is not the fine way to program, but it is the fastest way here. Originally this was a C code, but due to dependencies of a C++ library the language was changed.

Comment: @groenvit: Why do you believe that c code is faster as C++ code in this case? What do you believe will be inside the STL templates. Have you ever take a look into it? Have you ever measured the results? Instead of "thanks" the upvote button is the "money" we pay here on SO.

Comment: I was alluding to the "why you want to use char as data type". You got your Upvote from me and I am also very grateful for your answer. However, I am new here and do not yet have a 15 reputation, so it is not shown yet. But I will be happy to do it when the time comes. @Klaus